# react router dom is not updating class component when url change

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm a beginner in ReactJS. I would like to ask what is the proper way to update the component when the URL parameter is changing.

My code just not update the `CustomerDetails` component when URL changes from `customer/1` to `customer/2`.

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { CustomerList } from "./components/Customer/List";
import { CustomerDetails } from "./components/Customer/Details";

export class App extends React.Component<{}> {
  render(): React.ReactNode {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <nav>
            <li>
              <Link to="/customer">User list</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/customer/1">Test Customer details 1</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/customer/2">Test Customer Details 2</Link>
            </li>
          </nav>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/customer/:customerId" component={CustomerDetails} />
            <Route path="/customer" component={CustomerList} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

My `CustomerDetails` class component looks like this.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { RouteComponentProps } from "react-router-dom";

export interface CustomerDetailsParams {
  customerId: string;
}

export interface CustomerDetailsProps extends RouteComponentProps<CustomerDetailsParams> {
}

export interface CustomerDetailsState {
  customerId: string;
}

export class CustomerDetails extends React.Component<CustomerDetailsProps, CustomerDetailsState> {

  constructor(props: CustomerDetailsProps) {
    super(props);
    const params: CustomerDetailsParams = props.match.params;
    this.state = {
      customerId: params.customerId
    };
  }

  render(): React.ReactNode {
    return (
      <div className="customer-detail">
        <h2>customer details id: {this.state.customerId}</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

Why `Route` Component is not recreating `CustomerDetails` component? How it is working? This doesn't work when I'm switching between `customer/1` and `customer/2` links only.

I'm using `react-router-dom@5.1.2`, `react@16.12.0`, `react-dom@16.12.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'e setting state in the constructor of `CustomerDetails` but never updating it. So as far as the component is concerned, nothing has changed and no update is needed.

You probably don't need that duplicated prop in state at all, and can reference it in `props` directly like this:

```js
<h2>customer details id: {this.props.match.params.customerId}</h2>
```

Then it will update as expected.

Comment: I read in React documentation that we should never change props when component is mounted. There is only state that should be changed using `setState` method. So I 'm interested how should I design it according to good practices. This is really simple example but what If based on this `customerId` I will need to load some data from api?

Comment: You should never modify `props` ever (at least not directly), but here we aren't changing `props` just reading from it. If you need to read from the prop to fetch from an api, this will work just fine. Since this prop is a route parameter, it should really only change when the URL changes, and you shouldn't ever need to call `setState`

Comment: You are right. I'm not changing it but `Route` component is changing it on mounted component. Is that means my parent component `Route` is changing props for its children `CustomerDetails`? How to react on changing props in my component so I can load data from api for example?

Comment: You could do it in a [`componentDidUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) lifecycle method. Just add something like `if (prevProps.match.params.customerId != this.props.match.params.customerId) { //make api call with this.props..`

Comment: Thank You very much. And after I have my data from api I just need to build state based on it and set it using `setState`? Initial state should be configured in constructor because `componentDidUpdate` is not called for initial render. Is this correct?

Comment: That sounds correct based on my understanding of your case

Comment: I just found this awesome cheat sheet: http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/ It explains everything. Thank You very much :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you maybe use `exact` prop of `Link` and `Route` to declare the `/customer` route is only for `CustomerList` component, Hence, you should write like below:

```
  <nav>
    <li>
      <Link exact to="/customer">User list</Link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <Link to="/customer/1">Test Customer details 1</Link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <Link to="/customer/2">Test Customer Details 2</Link>
    </li>
  </nav>
```

And also on the `Route` using:

```
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/customer" component={CustomerList} />
    <Route path="/customer/:customerId" component={CustomerDetails} />
  </Switch>
```